# Can't write on file in Xelatex

Tags: xetex, pdf, miktex, windows

The code is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    hello world
\end{document}
```

WinEdt in WIN7

Error messages:

```
Command Line:   xelatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=1 "Chinese.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\work\Latex\Xelatex

This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(D:\work\Latex\Xelatex\Chinese.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for loaded.
("D:\Program Files (x86)\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("D:\Program Files (x86)\CTEX\MiKTeX\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
(D:\work\Latex\Xelatex\Chinese.aux) [1
! I can't write on file `Chinese.pdf'.
Please type another file name for output:
```

Any file name for out put will fail.

How to deal with this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This looks like a missing write permission to a directory or too less disk space left.

Comment: Also check that the file in question is not open in another program: Adobe Reader is a 'usual suspect' here.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.